# aws identity pool filter list users api on multiple conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

Is there a way to filter the result from list users api on multiple conditions. I want to get list of all users who have usernames from a list

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
client.list_users(UserPoolId='us-east-1_123456789', AttributesToGet=['email'], Filter="username =\"user_name_1\"")
```

the above code returns me only one username. Now if I want to get the same information for multiple usernames I cant seem to find a way to do it.

ex:

```
import boto3
usernames=['user_id1','user_id2']
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
client.list_users(UserPoolId='us-east-1_123456789', AttributesToGet=['email'], Filter="username =usernames")
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_RequestSyntax

You can only filter by strict equality or starts-with; no wildcards or arrays.

That said, `ListUsers` does not seem to have an specific api-calling limit, so you would be able to call it multiple times in quick succession until you had processed all the usernames.

Comment: It has a soft limit of [5 requests per second](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html)

Comment: Actually the rate limit for Cognito User Pools ListUsers is 25 requests per second (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits-soft).

Comment: It blows my mind that in today's day and age, this kind of filtering restriction is acceptable. Particularly on a service that the industry sees as the pinnacle of web infrastructure! Do better Amazon ffs!

Answer (score -4):

client.list_users() does have a limit of 60 users and this function is not pageable.

I faced a similar problem and created the filter-value that included element i of the list and contained the entire filter expression ahead of the actual function so that I was able to call that filter value within the function.

In the end, I looped over the filter-value that would adopt the new value of the lists element i.

Comment: The ListUsers function [is pageable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) via the **PaginationToken** parameter.